# Render functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Is it good or bad practice for using this kind of functions. How it affects to render speed and for optimization?

```
const ReactComponent: React.FC = (props) => {
const {isOpen} = props;

const renderIsOpen = () => {
  if (!isOpen) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div>Im open!</div>
}

return (
    <div>
      hello
      {renderIsOpen()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I hate this funcs, but my coworker uses this very often.

Comment: These functions are really neat and come in handy often times. The key is to not use them unnecessarily. I don't think it will have any effect on performance unless used in a really stupid manner. It is just a bad practice to use them when it is not needed.

Comment: I do not think it is a bad practice and I sometimes use them. although I think when you feel the need of using a render function (I mean in a real-life case, not this simple example) it is often an indication that you should at least consider moving that code into its separate sub component.

Answer (score 0):

While it works this seems overkill in lot of situations. The same could be obtain like this:

```
const ReactComponent: React.FC = ({isOpen}) => {
return (
    <div>
      hello
      {isOpen && <div>Im open!</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

It could become handy for some code clarity but again if the div you display is too complex you can anyway put it in a separate component.